# R: Using geom_ribbon() with melted dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add a geom_ribbon() to a ggplot() that is based on a melted dataframe?

For example, the simple example below should draw two lines. I would like to add a geom_ribbon() and use line2 as the min and line1 as the max (essentially filling in the area b/w the lines). A more complicated example will eventually have several non-linear lines in the dataframe and I will want to create a ribbon using particular line data as the lower and upper bounds.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(reshape2)
library(grid)
library(scales)

df.test <- 
   data.frame(
     x_cat = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4)),
     count = seq(1:4),
     line1 = seq(from = 1, to = 4, length.out = 4),
     line2 = seq(from = 0, to = 3, length.out = 4)
    )

df.melted <- melt( df.test[-2] )
p1 <- ggplot( data = df.melted , aes(x=x_cat, y=value, colour=variable ) ) +
      geom_line( aes(group=variable) ) +
      ylab( "Y Label 2" ) +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "white"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            legend.position = "bottom")

g<- ggplotGrob(p1)
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: No, not an easy way. `geom_ribbon` expects one column for `ymax` and one column for `ymin`. A good solution is to not melt your data. Or, in the case of multiple lines where need to first melt, you can then `dcast` it into appropriate shape.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Playing around with dcast did the job.